# Dell SupportAssist does not start

Tags: utility

`SupportAssist` on my `Dell XPS 15` stopped working recently. When I run it, is starts for a couple of minutes and then says `This is taking longer than expected. We recommend restarting your PC and trying again`.

[image]

Dell support got me to uninstall/reinstall it, which did not help. At that point they gave up and said the only remaining option was to reinstall Windows, which I'm obviously not going to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue for months, and discovered that it is being caused by a particular binary that is missing from the application directory.

I looked at the log file (SupportAssistAgent.log) in this folder:
C:\ProgramData\Dell\SupportAssist\Agent\logs\Application

Where it states this exception:

```
2023-04-09 21:15:34,343 [3.13.2.14] [17816 - 8] ERROR Dell.SupportAssist.Client.WebSocketServer.WebSocketServerManager - Error occurred while starting super socket server. Details:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I had a local copy of the .net 6 version of this library: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuation.UserSecrets.dll (version 6.x.x.x)

And so I copied it into the Application Folder:
C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssistAgent\bin

This fixed the issue for me, and Support Assist opened first time.

Comment: Yes thank you, I fixed my laptop the same way long time ago. Should have answered my own question...

Comment: Hopefully this saves someone else's sanity !